# removeFromParentViewController removes all the view controller from the stack

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I want to remove a view controller from the stack of view controllers and then navigate to a particular view controller. Say I have A,B,C,D,E view controller stack. I wish to remove E and then go to C. I use the following code

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];


for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers)
    {
        if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[noNetworkViewController class]])
        {
            [aViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        }
    }


     NSMutableArray *allbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];

    for (UIViewController *aViewController in allbViewControllers)
    {
        if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[messageViewController class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

The first for loop erases all the view controllers from the stack. Is there something I am doing wrong here. Please let me know.

Comment: do your other view controllers inherit from noNetworkViewController?

Comment: Going to C should remove both D and E.

Comment: @connor- No. It doesn't inherit.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be mucking around with a navigation controller's stack of view controllers using removeFromParentViewController:. Ever. That is flat-out wrong.

Furthermore, there is no reason to loop through a navigation controller's stack of view controllers and popping them one by one. There are methods like popToViewController:animated: and popToRootViewController that let you pop to any arbitrary view controller in the stack with one call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pop, you don't have to remove the other view from it's parent view. You can just pop to a view controller that is in the view controller array and back two from the top of the stack.

I would give a code example, but i'm not on my dev computer. If nobody has answered with more detail before tomorrow, I will add some code.

-Edit - Here is the line of code that I use to pop back 2 view controllers. I'm sure this could be done better ways, but it works.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-3] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the parent view controller property is populated by the navigation controller? The parent view controller is normally used for UIViewControllerContainment protocol conformance. UINavigationController does not conform to that protocol, which makes me think you're not going to be able to remove it from the navigation controller by calling that method. You can use – setViewControllers:animated: on your navigationController to assign the controllers. Just use the array you created with all the viewControllers.